# Trim special character from a column in R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R as below -

```
some_string <- c("::hello:world:", ":hello:world:again:::",":::::::hello::::")
df = as.data.frame(some_string)
df

            some_string
1        ::hello:world:
2 :hello:world::::again:::
3      :::::::hello::::
```

I would like to have `:` special character from this column between the words only once if it occurs multiple times. The output data frame should be -

```
           some_string
1          hello:world
2      hello:world:again
3           hello
```

Basically , I need the String separated by `:` but not at front and back of the String.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
gsub("^:+|:+$", "", some_string)
# [1] "hello:world"          "hello:world::::again" "hello"
```

Here we use `^` and `$` to anchor matches to the beginning or end of the string and use `|` to match those at the beginning "or" end.

To collapse multiple colons into one, you can also run

```
gsub(":+", ":", gsub("^:+|:+$", "", some_string))
# [1] "hello:world"       "hello:world:again" "hello"
```

by just replacing any instances of remaining duplicate colons with just one.

Comment: this code doesn't work if i have a string like `hello:::world`. It should return `hello:world`

Comment: I am sorry , I should edit the question accordingly.